# ExpressJs version route through header or query params

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have different version api developed using ExpressJs, I get version detail either through header or through query string like this  `example.com/users?version=1` and `example.com/users?version=2`
or I get in header.

I want to route my application api by query param I get through url
`app.js`

```
app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    app.use(require('./v'+req.query.version));
    next();
});
```

I have two version in folder `v1/index.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World! v01')
});

module.exports = app;
```

and `v2/index.js` as

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World! v02')
});

module.exports = app;
```

when I call api through url I only get response of version I call first

Like if I first call `example.com/users?version=1` than I will get response as `'Hello World! v01'`,

after this if I call `example.com/users?version=2` I get response as `'Hello World! v01'`

If I call version=2 first time after starting script I will get `'Hello World! v02'` response every time.

I don't want to have application like `example.com/v1` is their any way to get solve this version issue using query param or through header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you want to import dynamically may cause issues.

let say if I pass `example.com/users?version=23424`

```
// v1/index
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World! v01");
});
module.exports = router;

// v2/index
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World! v02");
});
module.exports = router;

// server
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const v1 = require("./v1/index");
const v2 = require("./v2/index");
app.use("/", (req, res, next) => {
const { version } = req.query;
  if (version !== "1" && version !== "2") {
    return res.json({
      message: "Not found",
    });
  }
  const router = version === "1" ? v1 : v2;
  router(req, res, next);
  next();
});
```

Comment: I tried your code, but if I call version=2 first time after starting script I will get `Hello World! v02` response every time and If I call version=1 first than I get `Hello World! v01` every time, it use same route even if I change version

Comment: @Jay I've updated my answer, hope that will solve this issue.